# How to enforce error handling in Rust when there is no actual result?

Tags: rust, error-handling

In Rust, errors are embedded in the return type of a function via Result<T,E>. That way, when I call a function that returns something of type T and I actually want to use that result, I have to somehow handle the error.

Now, in case I call some library function that generally does not return something, but might fail in a recoverable way, say it sets some flag in a complex structure. Now as I understand the way to write such a function is using Result<(), Error> as return type. But now the code calling this function has to explicitly handle the error and is not punished instantly if it does not. Doesn't this lead to me as a programmer having to always look twice at every functions signature in a library I'm using if I don't expect a result? In a language with exceptions I would still have to use some try-catch.

Can someone tell me if I just misunderstand something here, if there is maybe a better way to go about situations like that or if I am right and the programmer just has to be careful with library functions like that?

Comment: If you don't have a return value and error conditions are marked via side-effects, sounds like that function shouldn't be returning a `Result` then?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Take a look at [std::io::Read::read_exact](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact). It returns `std::io::Result<()>` since it has side-effect (reading into a buffer) can fail. But if it succeeded there is no value to return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::result::Result` is marked with [#[must_use]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-must_use-attribute) attribute. This means that if you forget to handle `Result` compiler will issue a warning. For example following code:

```rust
fn foo() -> Result<(), ()> {
    todo!()
}

fn bar() {
    foo();
}
```

compiles with warning:

```
warning: unused `Result` that must be used
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     foo();
  |     ^^^^^
  |
  = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
  = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
help: use `let _ = ...` to ignore the resulting value
  |
6 |     let _ = foo();
  |     +++++++
```

So you don't have to be extra careful just to avoid this situation. The compiler will help you.

Comment: You can also turn that into a compile error with `#![forbid(unused_must_use)]` at the root of your crate.